# How to install Java 8 runtime environment on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: java, macos, installation

I am running OS X 10.6.5. I want to use the current JRE because some software I would like to use depends on it (not browser applications). I downloaded the installer from Oracle (jre-8u60-macosx-x64.dmg), and ran it with administrator privileges.

The software depending on Java does not launch.

There is only this one version of Java installed, per the Java Control Panel.

When I type `java -version` in Terminal, I get the following error output:

> No Java runtime present, requesting install.
>   2015-09-03 12:43:15.675 java[1091:303] JLRequestRuntimeInstall: Error calling: CFMessagePortCreateRemote

A few dozen searches have failed to turn up useful insights for me.

**What am I doing incorrectly, or misunderstanding?**

Comment: @RealSkeptic Would you be so kind as to make that an answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install a JDK (development kit), it's assumed that as a programmer, you'll be using the command line tools. But the standalone JRE is considered a tool that's used by GUI-installed software, and that the software that needs it will know where to find it.

Nevertheless, it's possible to run the java command-line tool from Terminal, either by using the full path:

```
$ '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java' ClassName
```

Or by adding it to the shell path in `.bashrc` in your home directory:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin"
```

And then, after you open a new terminal (already-open terminals are not affected by changes to `.bashrc`), you can just type `java`.

The quotes are needed in the above commands, because there is a space in the path.